# Woocommerce how to send force Failed Order email for admin?

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

I don’t know why, but my website stopped sending Failed Order emails for admin. I tried to make a code, which can send this mail, but it still won’t send. Maybe anyone can help me? Maybe it is something bad in my code?

Code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_admin_failed_order_changed', 'admin_failed_order_email_notifications', 10, 4 );
function admin_failed_order_email_notifications( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ){
    // Only when order status is changed to 'cancelled'
    if ( $new_status != 'failed' ) return;

    // Send cancelled email notification
    WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Failed_Order']->trigger( $order_id ); 
}
```

I tried to write an code and expecting to edit/fix this code.